# Extjs 4 date picker

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I am using date picker of extjs 4.
I need to enable only three dates and 
to disable everything else. How
do I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest starting with the API docs for [Ext.menu.DatePicker](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.menu.DatePicker), which I assume that you are doing.

However, if there are only a total of three static dates ever available, why not use something besides a date picker for the task?

If you are picking from a set of dates that could be stored in an array, I'd suggest reading [this Sencha forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?7385-DateField-limit-to-available-dates-from-array&s=88a1185287212fa1767f3f8ec2f55531) about using DateField along with an array that disables all dates other than those specified in an array as follows:

```
dateArray = ["06/17/2007", "06/01/2007", "05/17/2007", "05/01/2007"];

dateField = new Ext.form.DateField({
    format: "m/d/Y",
    disabledDates: ["^(?!" + dateArray.join("|") + ").*$"],
    disabledDatesText: "Date not available."
});
```

Comment: It can be five or six but not much . And I need to use this component .

Comment: I know about disableDates but I need opposite

Comment: The code block allows you to use the "!" operator to disable all dates NOT in the array.